# MATLAB's gfdeconv vs. polynomial binary division

Tags: matlab, binary, bit-manipulation, checksum, crc32

I've read [*A Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms*](https://archive.org/stream/PainlessCRC/crc_v3.txt) by Ross N. Williams where he uses binary division to get the remainder of the division of the original message `1101011011` and poly `10011`. He arrives at a remainder of `1110`.

I've been attempting to use MATLAB's *gfdeconv* with the above example. The description in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/gfdeconv.html) says the function "divides polynomials over Galois field". I've entered the following into MATLAB:

```
[~, remd] = gfdeconv([1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1], [1 0 0 1 1])
```

However, I get a remainder of `[0 0 1]`.

Am I missing something here? Why doesn't MATLAB's *gfdeconv* produce the same remainder as the example in the Williams example? I understand that I'm probably suppose to flip and/or transpose the poly and/or the original message, but I am unsure of the method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the coefficients in the other order, i.e. the coefficient of 
1 (x<sup>0</sup>) first. You then need to provide the appended zeros first, so the correct usage is:

```
[q, r] = gfdeconv([0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1], [1 1 0 0 1])
```

The result is:

```
q =

     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1


r =

     0     1     1     1
```

where `r` is the expected result, also with the least significant bit first.